# Android: Handling large data list in very slow RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm new to Android dev and would like to show a list (row = image + text + button) in a view.

The list will contain more than 1000 items. Currently I'm using RecyclerView but it takes quite a while to load the information.

After adding logs, I find the data fetch (1000 items) takes around 1000ms, which is totally fine, **while it takes another 5000ms to show the list at first. After list shows, it's pretty smooth when scrolling up and down.**

My understanding is RecyclerView will automatically take care of the view creation for each row, such that

1. RecyclerView will only render a few items for the current screen, and anything below or need to be scrolled down will be rendered during runtime
2. RecyclerView will just render as many row as possible

If 1) is correct, then is there any chance to optimize? If 2) is correct, which mean I need to find a smart way to optimize, like pagination?

Since I'm pretty new to Android dev, I'm not sure the direction to dig into.

1. Should I go with pagination on the UI: fetch 1000 items and store in a List, then each time I'll load 10 items, and when scrolling reaches to the very bottom, load another 10 items, till the end?
2. Should I go with pagination on the data fetch: fetch 10 items and render 10 rows, and when scrolling reaches to the very bottom, fetch another 10 items and render the new 10 rows, till the end?

Which one is correct?

3. Also when scrolling down, how can the previous 10 items persist? Do I need to handle both up and down scrolling manually?

Sorry for the noob questions but hope I make this question clear.

Comment: Does fetch means pulling data from a server or from local db?

Comment: @mingchen doesn't matter in my case since fetch the whole batch only takes 1000ms, which is good enough, comparing to >5000ms UI rendering...

Answer (score 0):

Even though the recycler view generates views dynamically you should not manipulate huge data directly to the recyclerview.

Consider using Android's paging library. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging

Comment: Do you think fetching the data in one batch, store in a large array, and feed with scroll listener, is better than, fetching the data during scroll listener?

Answer (score 0):

> while it takes another 5000ms to show the list at first. After list
> shows, it's pretty smooth when scrolling up and down.

based on this, I would suggest you look at any data manipulation that you might did first (if any), because maybe the problem might not the recyclerView in the first place

if you are to optimize recyclerview, indeed there is a technique to use pagination for recyclerView

- if you want to use jetpack library, you can try [paging](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging)
- if you want to understand the technique and use vanilla implementation, this is a good link to start : https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView
- lastly, if you are facing performance issue when notifying data changes to recyclerView, please read about [diffutil](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/DiffUtil)

Comment: Do you think fetching the data in one batch, store in a large array, and feed with scroll listener, is better than, fetching the data during scroll listener?

Comment: i dont think so. in my opinion fetching data is more expensive than loading it in recyclerView. so when you are using pagination technique better to include data fetching as well